# Did Lucky the Pizza Dog do anything useful?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hawkeye-2021

Lucky the Pizza Dog intervenes bravely in the Robbery of the Black Market auction, and becomes the companion of Kate Bishop. After this initial contribution, Lucky seems to serve very little purpose in the narrative beyond humorously eating pizza offered by other characters. Did Lucky do anything else useful in the *Hawkeye* series, or was he just light relief?

Comment: In the comic book series, yes, he did:
[Lucky (Earth-616)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Lucky_(Earth-616))

Comment: Upvoting to offset downvote. Well thought out question, however rewatching the show might be a good way to answer it for yourself @EleventhDoctor if you have the ability.

Comment: You can't put a on price emotional support!

Comment: He was very precious and a good good boy.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this counts as an answer, but for me, I thought he swallowed the watch, and by Kate taking him home he will poop it out and gets to Hawkeye.

Maybe the reason is to make viewers think what I thought?